# Gradle could not find method c()

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, native

I have the following build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'c'

model {
    sources {
        c {
            source {
                srcDir "src/myapi/c"
                include "**/*.c"
            }
        }
    }
    platforms {
        x86 {
            architecture "x86"
        }
    }
    components {
        myapi(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            targetPlatform "x86"
        }
    }
}
```

`gradle myapiSharedLibrary` or `gradle tasks` or `gradle components`, all tasks fail with

> Exception thrown while executing model rule: sources { ... } @ build.gradle line 5, column 2
>
> Could not find method c() for arguments [build_1nkbkdtma2ngpuhlkja2lnmoa$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure5@2cefd5e6] on [] of type org.gradle.language.base.internal.DefaultProjectSourceSet.

The examples from the [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#sec:c_sources) do not seem to work for me properly.

Or am I doing something wrong?

Gradle version is

```
> gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.3.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-11-08 08:59:45 UTC
Revision:     e4f4804807ef7c2829da51877861ff06e07e006d

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 25.51-b03)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually solved it was moving `sources` into the `components` block like this:

```
    components {
        myapi(NativeLibrarySpec) {

            targetPlatform "x86"

            sources {
                c {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src/myapi/c"
                        include "**/*.c"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```